# Initialization idiom in ruby

Tags: ruby, initialization

There seems to be this initialization idiom in the ruby world where you do

```
def initialize(*someargs)
    #begin initialization
    yield self #so that the user can customize writable attributes
    #finish initialization
end
```

and the user then does:

```
some_object = SomeClass.new do |o|
     o.attribute1 = 'foo'
     o.attribute2 = 'bar'
end
```

The Rake TestTask uses this, for example.

Is there any point in continuing this now that ruby has keyword arguments?

Standard arguments could have easily replaced this idiom, but positional arguments are inconvenient to the user when there's many of them, and a hash argument is inconvenient to the developer as he or she would have to check for valid keys. The above idiom seemed to eliminate both inconveniences, but keyword args do too and additionally they eliminate the need for a block and a repeated `yielded_something.` initialization pattern.

E.g.:

```
class SomeClass
  def initialize(attribute1: nil, attribute2: nil)
  end
end

SomeClass.new(
     attribute2: 'bar',
     attribute1: 'foo'
)
#Order doesn't matter like with the block idiom
#Invalid keys raise an error, just like invalid attribute assignments in the block idiom
```

Is this correct or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

I think before keyword arguments, just passing a hash of options would have been fine, so I don't think arguments were the issue.  Probably this type of instantiation was done for readablity and flexibility.

It makes it much easier to read config options when written like this. And also it makes it easier to do something like this:

```
Config.new do |c|
  c.default_address = c.default_address + "/new"
end
```

Comment: Agreed on that default value decoration, though I think it'd be better to have a `Config::DEFAULT_ADDRESS` constant and base your new value on that. As for readability, you can get the same kind of readability with either a final hash argument or with keyword arguments. Simply do `Config.new(key1: 'something', key2: 'something2', ...) and split your keys among multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, maybe you are right. It may come down a bit to style and convention. It could be that people do it this way because that is what they are used to.

Answer (score 0):

The block syntax allows the user to add their own logic and call methods within the class which is especially useful for configuration objects.

For instance, RSpec's configuration object allows you to do something like:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before :each do
    # do something before each test
  end
end
```

This particular example isn't performed in the initializer, but depending on use case it could very well be.